# python to mysql query

Tags: python, mysql

im trying to convert this trending algorithm to mysql query

```
    # Rewritten code from /r2/r2/lib/db/_sorts.pyx

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from math import log

epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)

def epoch_seconds(date):
    td = date - epoch
    return td.days * 86400 + td.seconds + (float(td.microseconds) / 1000000)

def score(ups, downs):
    return ups - downs

def hot(ups, downs, date):
    s = score(ups, downs)
    order = log(max(abs(s), 1), 10)
    sign = 1 if s > 0 else -1 if s < 0 else 0
    seconds = epoch_seconds(date) - 1134028003
    return round(sign * order + seconds / 45000, 7)
```

mysql table have
 up_count down_count created_date
is this possible ?

i found this ,but this have a bug if the down_vode is bigger then you have LOG10(Zero) and this will crash

```
ORDER BY 
    LOG10(ABS(thumbs_up - thumbs_down) + 1) * SIGN(thumbs_up - thumbs_down)
    + (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created) / 300000) DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the MySql translation of you function:

```
SELECT ROUND((INTERVAL(up_count - down_count, -1, 0, 1) - 2) * LOG(GREATEST(ABS(up_count - down_count), 1), 10) + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(created_date) / 45000 , 7) FROM your_table
```